# c++ equivalent in Objective-C [alloc [init]]

Tags: objective-c, pointers

Am I right in saying the equivalent of:

```
NSMutableArray *foo;
foo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[foo release];
```

Is C++:

```
NSMutableArray *foo = new NSMutableArray();
delete foo;
```

ie. The 2nd line of the Obj-C does the dynamic memory allocation, while first just makes a pointer? In this case, what is the function of [init] VS. [alloc]?

thanks guys - I'm almost finding a bit of C++ is almost a hindrance to learning Obj-C!

Comment: I don't think that _ANY_ language has a equivalent for something like [xxx [alloc [init]];, including ObjC

Comment: You're technically correct, the best kind of correct!

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comment JustSid (fixed typo)

Comment: There's still a typo in there Pete.

Answer (score 2):

Internally C++ can be doing something very similar to alloc+init. In this case alloc does the actual memory allocation (the new), and init acts more or less as your constructor.

Answer (score 2):

`alloc` is the equivalent of `new()` and `init` is the equivalent of a C++ object constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I think the nearest C++ equivalent to Objective-C's two-stage alloc/init would be to call malloc to allocate a buffer, then use placement new to call the constructor for the previously-allocated memory block:

```
void *buffer = malloc(sizeof(NSMutableCPPArray));
NSMutableCPPArray *foo = new(buffer) NSMutableCPPArray();
```

In this example, the first line corresponds to `alloc`, dynamically allocating a new memory block for the object to use. The second line is similar to `init`, calling the constructor to initialize that memory block.

Of course, one key difference is that Objective-C's alloc/init pair is a fundamental and widely-used part of the standard Foundation library. Placement new, by contrast, is an odd and rarely-used corner of C++ that is loaded with [caveats and warnings in the online C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.10).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the basic semantic of the code you have showed, you have to consider the way memory is handled by the given programming languages. In Objective-C each object has a retain-count which is used when release is called (and an object needs a retain count of 0 before deletion). In C++ there is no such mechanism, and you have to handle memory all by your self when using new and delete (which can have memory leaks).

If you want memory management ala Objective-C you should check out the  header of C++0x which includes the shared_ptr object (which behaves more alike Objective-C).

Comment: Thanks yag I'd forgotten you get the allocated object count too.

Comment: shared_ptr has been available from Boost for quite some time, and I've found it extremely useful.